# Creating language and skill sections in resume

Tags: indentation, cv

How is it possible to get something similar to this:

```
Languages:
   Language 1           Native speaker
   Language 2           Fluent speaker
Skills:
   Working knowledge    Skill1, Skill2, Skill3
   Basic knowledge      Skill4, Skill5, Skill6
```

I tried using `\indent` but it doesn't always work as intended. Is there something similar to tab stops in Word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tabular`s can easily do that. The indentation can be adjusted by fixing the value `@{\hspace{2em}` and each column width can be controlled by adjusting the values `p{4cm}` and `p{5cm}` for first and second columns, respectively.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}
\begin{document}

\textbf{Languages:}\par\smallskip
\begin{tabular}{@{\hspace{2em}}p{4cm}p{5cm}}
Language 1 & Native speaker \\
Language 2 & Fluent speaker
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
\textbf{Skills:}\par\smallskip
\begin{tabular}{@{\hspace{2em}}p{4cm}p{5cm}}
Working knowledge & Skill1, Skill2, Skill3 \\
Basic knowledge   & Skill4, Skill5, Skill6
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `description` list and the style `nextline` from `enumitem` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,array}
\begin{document}
  \begin{description}[style=nextline]
    \item[Language]
       \begin{tabular}{@{}>{\raggedright}p{0.3\linewidth}
                          >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr0.8\linewidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}}
         Language 1 & Fluent \\
         Language 2 & Read
       \end{tabular}
    \item[Skills]
       \begin{tabular}{@{}>{\raggedright}p{0.3\linewidth}
                          >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr0.8\linewidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}}
         Working knowledge & Skill 1, skill 2 skill 3 \\
         Basic knowledge & Skill 1, skill 2 skill 3
       \end{tabular}
  \end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image]